# modeling tracking servo

Tags: control-theory

I was trying to simulate the simplified model of RDC (AD2S90) provided in link [image: tracking servo model]. The issue is to design proper compensator for this model to track constant velocity with zero velocity lag. Not very clear how to proceed. As suggested in the data sheet (page No.9) I tried to add a compensator (100/s * (s+100)/(s+1000)) between demodulator and the VCO. But from simulation(step response), it appears to oscillate. Where am I going wrong? Almost all the data sheets that I came across recommend the compensator with the above mentioned transfer function, but in simulation, it does not work. How to proceed?

Comment: It might be the problem of simulation. 
You have used frequency of $1000 Rad/sec$. This is a huge number.
In simulink, set the solver to fixed step and sampling time to at most $0.0001 sec$. Run the simulation again.